# task gate, interrupt gate, call gate

Tags: linux-kernel, x86, x86-64

I have been trying to read more about different gates in x86 architecture. If I understand correctly then interrupt and trap gate are used for hw and sw interrupt handling respectively. 
Whereas CALL gate is probably no more used, as ppl prefer replaced by SYSENTER and SYSEXIT.

I was wondering how task gates are used (I know they are used for hw task switch). What does that exactly mean? Does hw task refer to OS task/process. Or is it more like switching between two different instances of operating system. (May be on servers.)?

On a side note, can it happen that some of the interrupts are handled in the user mode. (Can we handle divide by zero interrupt in the user mode. If it can be then does that mean IDT handler entry for divide by zero contains address from the user space?)

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Everything you might want to know about interrupts and gates is in the [Intel developer manual, volume 3](http://www.intel.com/Assets/PDF/manual/325384.pdf). In short:

- Task gates were originally designed as a CPU-mediated method of performing task switching; the CPU can automatically record the state of the process during the task switching operation. These are not typically used in modern operating systems; the OS usually does the state-saving operations on its own.
- At least in Linux, all interrupt handlers are in kernel space and execute at ring 0. If you want to handle a divide-by-zero exception, you register a userspace signal handler for SIGFPE; the kernel-space interrupt handler raises the SIGFPE signal, indirectly triggering the userspace handler code (the userspace code is executed after returning from the interrupt handler).

Comment: I kind of went through the manual but the manual obviously does not mention that task gats are no more used in modern os. In my class project, I never used task gate and completely ignored it. So, I was confused if there is any use of task gates in modern os. Just to confirm, is timer interrupt mapped to interrupt gate?

Comment: "The interrupt descriptor table (IDT) associates each exception or interrupt vector 
with a gate descriptor for the procedure or task used to service the associated exception or interrupt." so yes, each interrupt is mapped to an interrupt gate. Note that the Intel manual does not discuss what is or is not actually used; it only describes what _can_ be used.

Comment: Several operating systems are designed to run on different architectures and therefore avoid using some Intel specific features. And, like you say, some features are just obsolete.

Answer (score 7):

The state of affairs is that only interrupt and trap gates was actually in use and stay in use now. In theory, both of them can be used as for s/w and for h/w event handling. The only difference between them is that interrupt gate call automatically prohibits future interrupts, that can be useful in some cases of hardware interrupt handling. 
By default people try to use trap gates, because unnecessary interrupt disabling is a bad thing, because interrupt disabling increase interrupt handling latencies and increase probability of interrupt lost.
Call gates was never been in actual use. It is inconvenient and not optimal way for system call implementation. Instead call gate, most of the operating systems use trap gate (int 0x80 in Linux and int 0x2E in Windows) or sysenter/sysexit syscall/sysrt instructions.
Task gate was never been in actual use too. It is not optimal, inconvenient and limited feature, if not ugly at all. Instead of it, operating systems usually implements task switching on its own side by kernel mode task stacks switching.
Initially, Intel delivered hardware support of multitasking by introduction of TSS (Task State Segment) and Task Gate. According to that features, processor is able to automatically store the state of one task and restore state of another one in reply to the request came from hw or sw. Sw request can be done by issuing call or jmp instructions with TSS selector or task gate selector used as instruction operand. Hw request can be done by hardware traping into the task gate in appropriate IDT entry. But as I've already mentioned, no one really uses it. Instead of it, operating systems use only one TSS for all tasks (TSS must be used in any case, because during control transfer from the less privileged segment to more privileged segment CPU switch stacks and it capture address of the stack for more privileged segment from the TSS) and make task switch manually.

In theory, interrupts and exceptions can be handled in user mode (ring 3), but in practice it is not useful and operating system handle all such events on the kernel side (in ring 0). The reason is simple, interrupt and exception handlers must always reside in the memory and be accessible from the any address space. Kernel part of address space is shared and the same in all address spaces of all tasks in the system, but the user part of address space is wired to the particular task. If you want to handle exception in user mode you will be forced to reprogram IDT on each task switch that will introduce significant performance penalty. If you want to handle interrupts in the same way you will be forced to share interrupt handlers between all tasks on the same addresses. As unwanted consequence, any task in the system will be able to corrupt handler.